# mulitple ComboBox validation on the same value

Tags: vaadin, vaadin23

I have a dynamic form where the user may add as many `ComboBox` as they need. All ComboBoxes contain the same predefined list of values. Is it possible somehow with the binding and validation mechanism to prevent the user from selecting the same value in two or more ComboBoxes? Show validation error in such case.

**UPDATED**

```
ComboBox<CompositeEntityResult> locationComboBox = new ComboBox<>("Location");
        locationComboBox.setRequiredIndicatorVisible(true);
        if (focus) {
            locationComboBox.focus();
        }
        locationComboBox.setItems(query -> {
            String searchQuery = createComboBoxSearchQuery(locationComboBox, query);
            VaadinUtils.invalidateQueryOffsetAndLimit(query);
            return locationService.findByNamePatternSorted(searchQuery, alreadyAddedLocationIds, alreadyAddedLocationUnknownNames, VaadinUtils.getCurrentLocaleIso6391(), AUTOCOMPLETE_PAG, AUTOCOMPLETE_PAGE_SIZE).stream();
        });
        locationComboBox.setAllowCustomValue(true);
        locationComboBox.addCustomValueSetListener(e -> {
            locationComboBox.setValue(new CompositeEntityResult(new Skill(e.getDetail(), null)));
        });
        locationComboBox.setItemLabelGenerator(e -> TranslationUtils.getTranslatedName(e.getNode()));
        locationComboBox.setRenderer(createCompositeEntityResultComboBoxRenderer(locationComboBox));
        locationComboBox.addValueChangeListener(v -> {
            addAlreadyAddedIdAndName(v.getValue(), alreadyAddedLocationIds, alreadyAddedLocationUnknownNames);
        });
        locationComboBox.getStyle().set("--vaadin-combo-box-overlay-width", "48em");
        binder.forField(locationComboBox)
                .asRequired("Specify location")
                .bind(dto -> locationCompositeEntityResult, (dto, v) -> {
                    if (v != null) {
                        Long locationId = v.getNode().getId();
                        if (locationId != null) {
                            dto.addAddedLocationId(locationId);
                        } else {
                            dto.addUnknownLocation(v.getNode().getName());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

I partially solved the issue and collect IDs in `addValueChangeListener`, then filter them on the database level. But the issue is that I need to allow user custom input as well. So I don't know how to prevent the same custom values right now.

Comment: Can you please share the code you use to build the form?

Comment: sure, updated the question with the code

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for bean level validation

```
@Test
public void beanLevelValidation() {

    final Bean bean = new Bean();
    final Binder<Bean> binder = new Binder<>(Bean.class);
    binder.setBean(bean);
    binder.withValidator(item ->
             item.getLocations().stream().distinct().count() == item.getLocations().size(),
            "Items have to be unique"
    );

    ComboBox<Object> locationComboBox = new ComboBox<>("Location");
    binder.forField(locationComboBox)
            .bind(
                    compositeEntityResult -> null,
                    (item, location) -> item.getLocations().add(location)
            );

    locationComboBox.setValue("sameValue");
    locationComboBox.setValue("differentValue");
    locationComboBox.setValue("sameValue");

    final BinderValidationStatus<Bean> validationStatus = binder.validate();
    assertThat(validationStatus.getValidationErrors().stream()
            .map(ValidationResult::getErrorMessage)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()), hasItem("Items have to be unique")
    );
}
```